# Why jemalloc's autogen.sh use "for i in autoconf; do ... done" not autoconf directly?

Tags: shell, autoconf, jemalloc

In jemalloc, autogen.sh has following code snippet:

```sh
for i in autoconf; do
    echo "$i"
    $i
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error $? in $i"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

I dont know why not directly write as:

```sh
echo "autoconf"
autoconf
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error $? in autoconf"
    exit 1
fi
```

I think the two code snippets are the same. And the second abviously cleared. I cannot understand why the first. Does it have any other meanings? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that this makes it easier to add an additional name to try instead of `autoreconf`, and then just tries one after the other until one has succeeded.